# This API call requires a valid app_id asp.net c# - facebook

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-c#-sdk

I want to post messages in my friends wall using a program. I will post the message using my asp.net application. I tried facebook's graph api. the problem is every time I have to use facebook provided login dialog to get the access token which requires manually enter username and password. Therefore I created a facebook app and obtained appid and app secret string. I am trying the below code to post a message in my wall first. I am getting the below exception.

```
 var fb = new Facebook.FacebookClient();


dynamic tokenInfo =
              fb.Get(
                String.Format(
                  "/oauth/access_token?client_id={0}&client_secret={1}&grant_type=client_credentials",
                  "1234567890",
                  "2bebebdf4709xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"));
   fb.Post("/100006xxxxxx/feed", new { message = "My Message" });
```

Error :

This API call requires a valid app_id

Answer (score 0):

Your friend must authorize your app and they need to grant the "publish to feed" privilege to your app.  To get this going, you need to have the user authorize your app via "Facebook Connect".  Use Facebook Connect to trigger the "authorize your app" process.  Once the app is authorized, the facebook api should recognize that your friend is logged into facebook (facebook api uses cookies to know that the user is logged into FB or not). Only then will issuing this command work. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks skidadon. Since I have my friend already in my list, can I just delegate my api to post on his wall. Something like, I give my all permission to the app and the app will act like me. In this way they don't want to install my app or grant permission for feed publish.

Comment: Facebook is very strict.  Your friend (and each friend thereafter) will need to authorize your app AND grant the publish feed permission.  this is a very explicit process and cannot be avoided.  Once you have this, you can use their token and make a call using your app to post on their behalf.  Not sure if that answers your question.

Comment: @pili You can't post on friends timeline through Graph API as of [6th Feb](https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/completed-changes/), so you need an app access token and your friend needs to be connected with the app.

Comment: Thanks @skidadon and ThePCWizard. So Now I have created a facebook app. meaning I have a appid and secret key and it is in sandbox mode. Now How can I make my fried to add this app and authorize?

Comment: @ThePCWizard, I got the app access token, which is something like  xxxx|xxxxxxxx. Then I created the test user for this app. This means the app is authorized with this test user right? Now in my app's code i am trying to use : client.Post("/me/feed", new { message = "Hi check this out.!!" });. This is getting posted in Testers wall. How can I make the app to post to friends wall after they authorize..

Answer (score 0):

```
            var fb = new FacebookClient(acctocken);
            var args = new Dictionary<string, object>();
            args["Message"] = "Hai Dear";
            fb.PostAsync("[friend id]/feed", args);
```

Hope Its Help You